# Can you put Italics in python?

Tags: python, italics

Is it possible?
I need it for a program I'm making and if not I'll try something else.

Comment: Fonts and other text decorations are not a part of the text. It doesn't matter much, what programming language you are using. The most important thing is how you plan to display your text. Using the same python, you will need different aproaches to make italics in HTML, PDF, image or terminal output.

Comment: What do you mean? Like, where should the italics be displayed? On a terminal, a web page, PDF, source code...? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: BTW, please take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out [ask] for tips.

Answer (score 4):

you can use ANSI escape codes in any language, however rendering that as expected is the responsibility of the terminal, for the most part they respect ANSI (with some notable exceptions)

```
print("\033[3mitalic\033[0m")
```

you can of course output Markdown or HTML italics if you are outputting that ...

If you are using some GUI library you probably just need to set the italic style

most text ui libraries have utility functions built around ANSI escape codes where you just do something like

```
my_string = "not italic " + italict("italic")+" text
```

which you can easily just implement as

```
def italic(txt):
    return f"\033[3m{txt}\033[0m"
```

on windows(cmd nor powershell nor conhost) this wont work ...

- ansii support is disabled by default, easy to enable however
- i dont think windows(cmd nor powershell nor conhost)  support the italic escape code, they support bold and underline and colors, but no italics

other windows terminal programs (not built in) do support full ansii codes

Comment: prints `←[3mitalic←[0m` in my console...

Comment: pycharm term or 99% of other terminals ... but windows terms sucks :( (evven cmd doesnt render it right)

Comment: Still prints `\x1b[3mitalic\x1b[0m` or `←[3mitalic←[0m` on cmd...

Comment: yeaah i editd my comment ... its easyish to enable ansii support in cmd/powershell but after that it still doesnt work for italics ... i think cmd.exe and powershell and conhost terminals simply dont support the italic ansii code  ... (they do support bold underline colors etc)

Comment: *"ansii" -> ANSI

Comment: I know I saw your edit after and was too lazy to fix it until your comment :P (thank goodness i dont get paid for my ability to spell or grammar correctly)  (thanks though I do appreciate it :) )

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it myself but I know that the functionality exists in this library: [Rich](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/introduction.html)

> Rich is a Python library for writing rich text (with color and style) to the terminal, and for displaying advanced content such as tables, markdown, and syntax highlighted code.

Comment: I upvoted this since there is some possibility (not going to bother testing it) that via some magic rich can output italics in cmd/powershell where ansii escape codes cannot

Comment: Doubtful... But yeah.